# SQL student class registration

Tags: sql, database-design

I have following tables:

- login - [`username`, `password`, `usertype`, `userid`],
- student - [`student_id`, `student_name`, `grade`]
- course - table [`courseid`, `coursename`, `day`, `time`, `location`]
- semester - table [`year`, `term`, `department]`

I am not able to make the connectivity or relationship between particular entities, like if particular student logs in then that persons course details should be displayed.

My work flow is:

- Adviser can open courses for particular professor.
- Student can Enroll and see the schedule for particular term of year
- Professor also can see the schedule for particular term of year

Comment: Since it's **your** database, **you** need to set how **your** tables are related by identifying Primary and Foreign keys.

Comment: begin by writting down your entities (some say it's better on paper, I like to just use a text editor). Then for each entity write the data that needs to be saved in the database. Then write the connection between entities (for instance, a person entity might have a student role or a professor role (sometimes both in the same time). If something is not clear to you after you have written everything down, ask a question with the full entities data.